# servlet not responding back to ajax request

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

servlet is not sending back response to ajax code. Plaease help!!!

html code, here output should be printed

this is ajax code in javascript

```
 <script language="javascript">
    reqObj=null;

    function getPrice(){

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
              reqObj=new XMLHttpRequest();
           }else {
              reqObj=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

            reqObj.onreadystatechange=process;


           var area = document.getElementById('product').value;
           var fType= document.getElementById('size').value;




         reqObj.open("POST","./getPricefromSize?pro="+area+"&size="+fType,true);
        reqObj.send(null);


    }
    function process1(){

        if(reqObj.readyState==4){
           var prce=reqObj.responseText;

           document.getElementById("price").innerHTML=prce;

        }

    }


    </script>
```

this is my servlet code:

```
  String str=request.getParameter("pro");
    String str1=request.getParameter("size");


     PrintWriter  out1=response.getWriter();


      System.out.println("pro: "+str+"size: "+str1);

        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:linpaws","system","oracle");
       st=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        rs=st.executeQuery("select price from labpro where usernm='"+labid+"' and product='"+str+"' and sze='"+str1+"'");
      rs.first();
        price=rs.getString(1);


        System.out.println("price"+price);
       out1.write(price);

       rs.close();
    st.close();
```

output is printed in console. But not showing in ajax call

Comment: Does your question or your code have the "process" vs "process1" typo?

Comment: @SteveC there is function process1

Comment: Debugging check: temporarily add a doGet() to your servlet so you can navigate to it in a browser. What do you see in the browser window then (with the proper parameters passed of course)? Alternatively you could install a HTTP requester plugin for your browser so you can mimic what the ajax call is doing.

Comment: @SteveC there is another ajax request, there i have used function named process. hence i used process1 as another function ijn above code

Comment: and "reqObj.onreadystatechange=process"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some bits out of your code:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
 }
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.asp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp should put you on the right track.

Another reason its not working is your assigning process to your onreadystatechange e.g 
`onreadystatechange=process` but `process` must exactly match the name of the function your assigning which in your case is `process1` so the code would become `reqObj.onreadystatechange=process1`.

Comment: Another reason its not working is your assigning process to your onreadystatechange e.g onreadystatechange=process but "process" must exactly match the name of the function your assigning which in your case is process1 so the code would become reqObj.onreadystatechange=process1;